# Map - get key value in aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

I'm trying to get the key/value pair in the aura component

Aura component:

```
<aura:attribute name="countryMap" type="Map"  default="{}"/>
<aura:attribute name="currentCountry" type="String" />

<aura:iteration items="{!v.countryMap}" var="cus" indexVar="key">
       here is the key:= {!cus.key} - {!cus.value}<br/><br/>
</aura:iteration>
```

Controller.js:

```
 var countryMap = component.get("v.countryMap");
 var newcountryMap = {
            'us': $A.get("$Label.c.countryUSAURL"),
            'ca': $A.get("$Label.c.countryCANURL")
        };
langMap = newLangMap;
```

Does not work, `countryMap` is empty

Comment: try `Object.assign(countryMap , newcountryMap );` but you can not iterate the directly. you have to do some mimic like https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140608/how-to-iterate-over-map-in-salesforce-lightning-component

Comment: I have a solution here that uses a custom value provider: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/231968/550